# Category name update with category Id in magento2

Tags: magento2, category

I am trying below code to update category name and parent id by categoryId,

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory

) { 
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;      

}
 $catId = 5;
$name = 'test';
try {
   $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->setStoreId(1)->load($catId);
   $category->setName($name);
   $category->save();
  echo "Category is updated successfully";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

But category name is not updating for me. Where i am wrong please anyone suggest me

Comment: Have you checked value for correct store id after saving?

Answer (score 0):

We need to identify the id of category tree root. Then, we created an instance of the category, set its path, parent_id, name, etc.

```
$parentId = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::TREE_ROOT_ID;

$parentCategory = $this->_objectManager
                      ->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
                      ->load($parentId);
$category = $this->_objectManager
                ->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
//Check exist category
$cate = $category->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('name','test')
            ->getFirstItem();

if(!isset($cate->getId())) {
    $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath())
        ->setParentId($parentId)
        ->setName('test')
        ->setIsActive(true);
    $category->save();
}
```

You can try this it's working fine for me.

Comment: is it possible to update with category id?

Comment: Let me first try and let you know.

Comment: Ok try once, please update me once it is worked for you